# Does `ResultQuery#fetchAsync()` work with r2dbc in jOOQ 3.15.1?

Tags: jooq, nonblocking, r2dbc

I am wanting to use non-blocking r2dbc *without* 'using a third party reactive stream API', and currently have this working when I configure the `DSLContext` with JDBC (ie. all the records are printed):

```
     // appended to a jOOQ select query
     .fetchAsync()
     .thenApply{ it.map(mapping(::Film)) }
     .whenComplete { result, _ -> println( result ) }
```

however, if I configure the `DSLContext` to use r2dbc (without any other changes), the `println( result )` prints `null` :-(

I:

- am using Kotlin, but not bridging to coroutines yet ... only the above calls are involved
- am using `io.r2dbc:r2dbc-mssql:0.8.6.RELEASE`
- don't know if r2dbc is 'working' in any sense ... I'm relying on jOOQ to hit me with an exception if not ... I've not seen a single piece of data relayed by r2dbc at this stage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of jOOQ 3.15.1, this isn't possible yet, see https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/11717. It's likely this will be fixed in a 3.15.x patch release

Comment: OK, since r2dbc hasn't yet achieved a release that's mature/complete, I guess we'll let you have a little more time to fine-tune things :-) .    Meanwhile, I am grateful to have jOOQ as an abstraction layer between me and the database-connectivity plumbing, and I can easily write my code in a reactive style *now* even though, because of JDBC, the thread does in fact block on I/O.

Comment: @DavidBullock yeah it's all bleeding edge

Comment: Yep.  More like driving a rocket while you're on the tip of the rocket, holding on for dear life and hoping the rocket doesn't smash into something.  I think we're called 'thrillseekers'?!  Other names spring to mind ...

Comment: @DavidBullock: blocking, synchronous code is probably fine, too ;-)

Comment: I just discovered [kotlinx-coroutines-jdk9](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-jdk9/kotlinx.coroutines.jdk9/index.html) which bridges co-routines to a `java.util.concurrent.Flow`.  Can I get reactive with jOOQ and r2dbc using this pathway?  (I have a bit more reading to do before I try).

Comment: jOOQ supports the Flow API as well as its Java 8 predecesdpr reactive streams. It might work. I'll do some experiments in that direction, myself, soon